Where does the Mentat, Thufir Hawat, go in Dune Part two?
For most of the major / minor characters from Dune, we learn about their fate in Dune Part two. For example, there is a high ranking Atreides military officer, a minor character, who reminds Duke Leto that he needs to go inside to protect himself as a storm is coming; after being captured, he is seen fighting Feyd-Rautha Harkonnen in an Arena without being drugged.
I am wondering what has happened to Thufir Hawat, The Mentat of House Atreides. Has he been mentioned anywhere in Dune Part two?

We don't know what happens to him in that movie; not mentioning Thufir Hawat is a director's artistic choice, as explained by Villeneuve himself in an interview to ScreenCrush:

But I know you can’t squeeze every last bit of the book you love into the films. Was there one thing that was maybe the hardest to cut from your Dune, where you loved it from the book but you realized it was not needed on screen?

I was in love with Thufir Hawat [played in Dune: Part One by Stephen McKinley Henderson]. It’s a character that I absolutely adore. But I had to make the bold choice to make a Bene Gesserit adaptation, and to focus the movie on that sisterhood. I wish there was more Thufir Hawat. That’s what I would say.



In the book he is captured by the Harkonnens and forced to work for them. He is given a poison that will kill him unless he takes an antidote every day, which is given to him in his food, so he can't leave without dying. Perhaps we will find out in Dune part 3 whether this also happened in Villeneuve's Dune universe.
This is also shown in the 1984 movie, but it might not be present in all versions of that film, since I don't remember seeing the relevant scene until I watched the extended edition. In the 1984 version Thufir has to milk a cat to get the antidote.
In the end of the book he

 dies by his own hand rather than carry out the Emperor's orders to kill Paul.

(hat tip to Valorum and Sotto Voce in the comments)

"This is also shown in the 1989 movie, but only in the extended edition" -> might depend on the country, but I have the original 1984 footage, and it shows the cat scene

@OldPadawan I've corrected the year. I'll look into which version that appears in - I watched the David Lynch version many times on VHS but I never saw the cat scene until I watched the Alan Smithee one.

You may wish to mention that he dies by his own hand at the end of Dune rather than carry out the Baron's orders to kill Paul.

@Valorum slight correction: the order came from the Emperor.  The Baron had been dead for hours (stabbed with a poisoned needle by the young Alia) before Hawat was brought with the surviving members of the Emperor's court before Paul.

@SottoVoce - You're not wrong
